# TFS query for items completed yesterday to use weekdays

Tags: tfs

I have a query for "items completed yesterday" which is super useful in standups.

[image: TFS Query]

But `@today - 1` seems to look at calendar days, not weekdays/workdays meaning that my query isn't useable on Mondays. Is there a way to tweak it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately we cannot achieve that.

You can [Set working days](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-working-days?view=vsts) for team's sprint planning and tracking when calculating capacity and sprint burndown, however it's not apply to work item queries.

So, as a workaround you can create another query with `Closed Date =  @today - 3` specified if you are using the normal working days...(Means the "Yesterday" is Friday)

More information please see [Query by date or current iteration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=vsts).